# mkdocs static app not rendered properly when deployed using azure pipelines on static webapp

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, mkdocs, mkdocs-material

I have created a mkdocs static website using mkdocs-material theme.

It works perfectly fine on local machine and website is rendered properly using http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Next when I deploy it using Azure pipelines, the deployment (build and deploy) is successful but the website is not rendered properly

mkdocs.yml file contents

```
    site_name: test123
    site_description: test123
    site_url: https://test123.azurewebsites.net/
    nav: 
        - 'index.md'
        - Level 1: 
          - Level 1 Overview: overview.md
    theme: 
      name: material
```

Website looks like hyperlinks and not following the material themes, rendering of the website is not proper.

Attached sample snip of how the website looks like

[image]

Additional steps tried

1. Add css/extra.css with below content

   code, .rst-content tt, .rst-content code {
   white-space: pre;
   }
2. Add inputs in the FtpUpload@2 in deploy stage in the yaml file for azure pipelines which looks like below

````
   
   trigger:
   - main
   
   pool:
     vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
   
   stages:
   - stage: build
     jobs:
       - job: build
         steps:
         - task: UsePythonVersion@0
           inputs:
             versionSpec: '3.x'
             addToPath: true
             architecture: 'x64'
         - task: CmdLine@2
           inputs:
             script: 'python3 -m pip install mkdocs'
         - task: CmdLine@2
           inputs:
             script: 'python3 -m pip install --upgrade mkdocs'
         - task: CmdLine@2
           inputs:
             script: 'python3 -m pip install mkdocs-material'
         - task: CmdLine@2
           inputs:
             script: 'python3 -m pip install --upgrade mkdocs-material'
         # Build the HTML content using MkDocs
         - task: CmdLine@2
           inputs:
             script: 'python3 -m mkdocs build'
         # Copy the generated HTML to the staging location provided by the pipeline
         - task: CopyFiles@2
           inputs:
             SourceFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
             Contents: '**/site/**'
             TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
         - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
           inputs:
             targetPath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)'
             artifact: 'html'
             publishLocation: 'pipeline'
   - stage: deploy
     dependsOn: build
     condition: succeeded()
     jobs:
       - deployment: deploy
         environment: docs
         strategy:
          runOnce:
            deploy:           
             steps:
             - task: FtpUpload@2
               inputs:
                app_location: 'src'
                api_location: 'api'
                output_location: 'site'
                skip_app_build: true
                credentialsOption: 'serviceEndpoint'
                serverEndpoint: 'endpoint-connection-secret'
                rootDirectory: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/html
                filePatterns: '**'
                remoteDirectory: '/site/wwwroot'
                clean: false
                cleanContents: true
                preservePaths: false
                trustSSL: false
   ```

PS : For file upload on Static App I am using FTP credentials
````

Answer (score 0):

In your ***Azure DevOps pipeline***, You can ***build the mkdocs application locally and then add it in your Azure DevOps repository***:-

[image]

***Create one sample static web app with Source as others and copy the Deployment token*** from the Overview tab, like below:-

[image]

Now, Create an ***Azure DevOps YAML pipeline and select AzureStaticWebApp task and fill the details as per the YAML script*** ***below***:-

[image]

[image]

```yaml
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: AzureStaticWebApp@0
  inputs:
    app_location: 'site'
    azure_static_web_apps_api_token: 'xxxxxxxx753f4ff9168da1e36d2f6c7e3-62a0e918-67c1-4e36-8a11-fxxxxxx'
```

**Output:-**

[image]

[image]

As a workaround, I build ***mkdocs app locally and deployed it via github actions*** by uploading the application in my github repository, And the mkdocs page rendered successfully.

`site directory` got created after the build like below:-

[image]

In my static Web app I selected `"/site"` as a app location by selecting github as an option with framework set to custom like below:-

[image]

After creating ***the Static Web app the mkdocs app was deployed successfully*** like below:-

[image]

In your pipeline check where the build is getting created by referring to the [predefined variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) and then use `site` folder as app location. As, The Deployment requires build folder only.